# Connect a Lambda Function to an EC2 Instance running Windows Server 2019 w/ SQL Server Standard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, ssis, windows-server-2019

I am looking to replace several SSIS packages with Lambda functions. The Lambdas are triggered when a file is uploaded to S3, the Lambdas then pull that file, process it, and update an on-instance MS SQL database. My main problem is that I am unsure how to get the Lambda to connect to the EC2 instance, and then to the DB that is running on that instance.

The Lambdas will have a Python 3.7/3.8 runtime, and the EC2 instance is using the Microsoft Windows Server 2019 with SQL Server 2017 Standard AMI. I've found some resources that discuss setting up the Lambda Execution Role, and then all the VPC/subnet/security group configuration, and I believe that I have all of that set up correctly. Beyond that though, I'm a little lost because most of this stuff is still pretty new to me.

My main goal here is to be able to at least get a "Hello, world!" proving that I can connect the Lambda to the on-instance DB and then just go from there. Thank you in advance for any guidance!

Comment: Welcome to the community! What have you tried and what went wrong? Having the VPC/subnet/sg configuration should let your lambda connect to your EC2

Comment: As mentioned above welcome. Definitely to have Lambda connecting with your SQL you need to have Lambda running inside VPC, so make sure this is properly configured (I am not considering public IP as it is not a best practice). Your question is a little bit confuse, it is not clear if your DB engine is MS SQL Server or MySQL. Would be nice to fix this on your question and also mention what your already tried and didn't work.

Comment: Hello, thank you all for the warm welcome. Sorry about the confusion about the DB engine, the question has been updated. I was provided [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWbU_OnkFOo) resource to look at, but it seems like there are so many steps to get it working that there has to be a simpler method. I think I'm also just having a conceptual problem with it. The leap of complexity of having these components on my machine to having it be Lambda -> EC2 -> MS SQL, plus I'll eventually be putting this all into a SAM template, it's just all a little overwhelming.

Comment: I believe that I have set up the Lambda to run inside of the same VPC as the instance. I think the next step to connect would just be with the Python code and then testing the function, but Python isn't my primary language and I'm having trouble figuring that part out as well.